# Using NDEigensystem to solve coupled eigenvalue problem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I want to find the Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions for the following Eigenvalue problem

[image]

I tried to solve this numerically

```
pars=Rationalize[{L-> 6.9,A->0.0133,a0->410,
c1a->0.003,c2a->0.002,c1p->-2.5 10^-6,c2p->4.3 10^-6}];
```

I defined to Operator like above

```
op={-(a0^2/A)D[\[Phi]2[xi],xi], -A D[\[Phi]1[xi],xi]}/.pars
```

I am not shure how to use the

> DirichletCondition

but I tired this

```
bc={DirichletCondition[\[Phi]2[xi]==c1p \[Phi]1[xi],xi==0],
DirichletCondition[\[Phi]2[xi]==c2p \[Phi]1[xi],xi==L]}/.pars
```

Unfortunately Mathematica could not understand my input

```
NDEigensystem[Flatten[{op,bc}],{\[Phi]1[xi],\[Phi]2[xi]},{xi,0,L}/.pars,4]
```

[image]

Did I make a mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: The missing message text is: `NDEigenvalues::fembdcc: Cross-coupling of dependent variables in DirichletCondition[\[Phi]2==-(\[Phi]1/400000),xi==0] is not supported in this version.`

Comment: Thanks! So I can't solve it with this version, at all?

Comment: `NDEigensystem` can not handle inhomogeneous `DirichletConditions` and thus it can not handle cross coupling of boundary conditions. You could try to manually make a solution. But the coupled ODEs are also convection dominant which makes it harder. Do you have an expected solution?

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old and has an explicit analytic solution given, but here is a numerical method to confirm the roots, which works for cross-coupling of the boundary conditions as seen here.

I have a package for numerically calculating solutions of eigenvalue problems using the Evans function via the method of compound matrices, which is [hosted on github](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod). See my [answers to other questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=compoundmatrixmethod) or the github for some more details.

First we install the package (only need to do this the first time):

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Then we first need to turn the ODEs into a matrix form $\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{y}$, using my function `ToMatrixSystem`:

```
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]

pars = Rationalize[{L -> 6.9, A -> 0.0133, a0 -> 410, c1a -> 0.003, 
    c2a -> 0.002, c1p -> -2.5 10^-6, c2p -> 4.3 10^-6}];
eqns = {-(a0^2/A) D[ϕ2[xi], xi] == λ ϕ1[xi], -A D[ϕ1[xi], xi] == λ ϕ2[xi]}
bcs = {ϕ2[0] == c1p ϕ1[0], ϕ2[L] == c2p ϕ1[L]}
sys = ToMatrixSystem[eqns, bcs, {ϕ1, ϕ2}, {xi, 0, L}, λ] /. pars
```

The object `sys` contains the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, as well as similar matrices for the boundary conditions and the range of integration.

Now the function `Evans` will calculate the Evans function (also known as the Miss-Distance function) for any given value of $\lambda$; this is an analytic function whose roots coincide with eigenvalues of the original equation.

FindRoot will then find solutions for a given start point:

```
FindRoot[Evans[λ, sys], {λ, 1}]
 (* {λ -> -12.5116} *)
```

And this gives the same values as for the analytic solution given in the other answer.

```
λ/.FindRoot[Evans[λ, sys], {λ, -12 + # I}] & /@ Range[-1860, 1860, 186] // Quiet
(* {-12.5116 - 1866.74 I, -12.5116 - 1680.07 I, -12.5116 - 1493.39 I, -12.5116 - 1306.72 I, 
  -12.5116 - 1120.05 I, -12.5116 - 933.372 I, -12.5116 - 746.697 I, -12.5116 - 560.023 I, 
  -12.5116 - 373.349 I, -12.5116 - 186.674 I, -12.5116, -12.5116 + 186.674 I, 
  -12.5116 + 373.349 I, -12.5116 + 560.023 I, -12.5116 + 746.697 I, -12.5116 + 933.372 I, 
  -12.5116 + 1120.05 I, -12.5116 + 1306.72 I, -12.5116 + 1493.39 I, -12.5116 + 1680.07 I, 
  -12.5116 + 1866.74 I} *)
```

Comment: for the coupled odes, if an initial guess of the eigval is not available, is it possible to replace the `FindRoot` with `NSolve`, for example, `\[Lambda] /. NSolve[Evans[\[Lambda], sys] == 0]`. Or is there any way to obtain all roots of `Evans` function without an initial guess? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that you can find all roots easily I'm afraid, I don't think it will work in `NSolve`. There is a function to calculate the Winding Number of a contour, which tells you how many roots lie within a circle, although be slightly careful that you have enough points when using that.

Answer (score 2):

I have computed the analytic solution of the Eigenvalue problem above

With the Eigenvalues

```
\[Beta] -> Log[(Sqrt[A + a0 c1p] Sqrt[A - a0 c2p])/Sqrt[(A - a0 c1p) (A + a0 c2p)]]

ev[k_] := (a0 (I k \[Pi] + \[Beta]))/L
```

with some constant beta and the Eigenfunctions

```
ef[xi_,k_] := {{Cosh[(xi ev[k])/a0]/c1p-(a0 Sinh[(xi ev[k])/a0])/A},
              {Cosh[(xi ev[k])/a0]-(A Sinh[(xi ev[k])/a0])/(a0 c1p)}}
```